# Obtaining OS X app store receipts on test builds

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

Been trying tonight to obtain a receipt for my app.  However, I've been unsuccessful.  Here's the steps I've done:

- Code signed with developer cert
- Made sure minimum version in the info.plist is 10.7
- Checked for the presence of the receipt file and called exit(173) if not found
- Built from XCode 4.2
- Added a new version of the app and some in-app metadata in itunesconnect. The app status is now waiting for a new binary.

I've then done clean, build, right clicked on the app in XCode's project view and opened it in finder to launch it, hopefully failing validation and pulling a receipt back from the store.

However, this never seems to happen (don't get asked for any itunes login etc) and the app terminates immediately.

I've also gone through an entire build/archive/create installer type process as well but that didn't pop up the login either.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Following on from this, just to help anyone out who encounters the same problem.  I've ran console.app (which I was unaware existed at the time), and it reports my app as not being signed.  Not sure why, I will have to look into that at the weekend.

Answer (score 3):

I've finally got it working.  In case anyone else has a similar problem, the real help for me was finding out about console.app.  In running this I could see my app didn't appear to be signed.

I deleted all the certificates etc and re-installed new ones.  Seems it HAS to be the Mac 3rd party developer.  Nothing else seemed to work.